# Eclipse BIRT - Unnecessary inline style with external CSS when rendering HTML

Tags: eclipse, reporting, birt

I am designing a report using external CSS with BIRT 2.5. When BIRT renders the html report, it creates copies of each external style to inline styles (name style_x) in the resulting html.

The report.design contains:

```
<list-property name="cssStyleSheets">
<structure>
<property name="fileName">… mycss.css</property>
<property name="externalCssURI"> http://.../mycss.css </property>
</structure>
</list-property>
```

The resulting html contains:

```
<style type="text/css">
.style_0 {…}
.style_1 {…}
….

</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://.../mycss.css"></link>
```

For each reference of my styles, the rendered html elements use both styles usually like this:

```
<div class="style_x myclass" …. > …. </div>
```

Is there any way to get rid of the useless inline styles when rendering html?

Answer (score 0):

Something similiar happened to the *XLS Output in BIRT 3.7.0*, which is apparently fixed in version 3.7.1 RC3.

Google this for more info: http://www.google.de/search?q=birt+duplicate+style